# Tableview style like in ios5 reminders app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5

I want to try out tableview interface like in ios 5 reminders application. It's tableview look like grouped style  and section don't have rounded corners. So I have few questions about this.

1. Is this really grouped style tableview? I have set the corner radius of the tableviewcell's contentview layer to 0. But it didn't change the rounded corners.
2. How ever I managed to create a such tableview with plain style and inserting empty view as a header section and setting cell border width. But now the problem is cell separator look like 2 times bigger than the cell boarder width. (I am setting the border to cell)
3. Is there anyway I can get reference to section view? (So I can set the border to that view)

Comment: I think its a custom UITableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a table with plain style but with custom cells. I suggest to try my [TableKit](https://github.com/onegray/UITableKit) library. Probably I will add "Reminder-like" cell theme to the samples.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll check and let you know any improvement suggestions. :)